# Writing procedures in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am very new for TCL. Just I want to know that how to write TCL procedures without argument and how to call and how to execute it.

Answer (score 21):

To write a procedure that doesn't take any arguments, do this:

```
proc someName {} {
    # The {} above means a list of zero formal arguments
    puts "Hello from inside someName"
}
```

To call that procedure, just write its name:

```
someName
```

If it was returning a value:

```
proc example2 {} {
    return "some arbitrary value"
}
```

Then you'd do something with that returned value by enclosing the call in square brackets and using that where you want the value used:

```
set someVariable [example2]
```

To execute it... depends what you mean. I assume you mean doing so from outside a Tcl program. That's done by making the whole script (e.g., `theScript.tcl`) define the procedure and do the call, like this:

```
proc example3 {} {
    return "The quick brown fox"
}
puts [example3]
```

That would then be run something like this:

```
tclsh8.5 theScript.tcl
```

Answer (score 6):

You can define a procedure like this:

```
proc hello_world_proc {} {
  puts "Hello world"
}
```

And you can execute it by simply writing:

```
hello_world_proc
```

If you want to use a return value of the procedure, you can do:

```
# Procedure declaration
proc hello_world_proc2 {} {
  return "Hello world"
}

# Procedure call
puts [hello_world_proc2]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
proc myProc {} {
    # do something
}

# call proc
myProc
```

Answer (score 3):

Te official Tcl website has some documentation on functions (procedures) that could help you at https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm.

**Procedure with no argument**

If you don't need any argument here is how to write the procedure you want:

```
proc funcNameNoArgs {} {
    puts "Hello from funcNameNoArgs"
}
```

And you can call it as follows:

```
funcNameNoArgs
```

**Procedure with arguments**

Now let's say you need arguments in the future. Here is the way to write that precedure in TCL:

```
proc funcNameWithArgs {arg1 arg2 arg3} {
    puts "Hello from funcNameWithArgs "
}
```

You can call that function by doing:

```
funcName arg1 arg2 arg3
```

**Here is a piece of code for you to try!**

Remember to define functions before you call them, or you will get an error.

Try to copy paste this code in your interpreter to get started and play with it:

```
proc funcNameNoArgs {} {
    puts "Hello from a function with no arguments"
}
funcNameNoArgs
proc funcNameWithArgs {arg1 arg2 arg3} {
    puts "Hello from a function with 3 arguments"
    puts $arg1
    puts $arg2
    puts $arg3
}
funcNameWithArgs "Argument 1" "Argument 2" "Argument 3"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yours the only one that includes a description on how to *call* a defined procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax of procedure

```
proc <Name Of procedure> {No of arguments, if u want don't need simply left empty} { 
<Body>
 }
```

Let See the Example:

1. Without Arguments:

   ```
   proc Hello_eg { } { puts "Hello I M In procedure" }
   ```

How to run:

step 1: write tclsh on prompt

step 2: write the procedure as per above mention

step 3: write just the procedure name (i.e Hello_eg) to run the procedure

2.With Arguments:

```
proc Hello_Arg { first second }
{
   puts "The first argument is: $first"
   puts "The Second argument is: $second"
}
```

How to run this:

step 1: write tclsh on prompt

step 2: write the procedure as per above mention

step 3: write just the procedure name with arguments (i.e Hello_Arg Ramakant Singla) to run the procedure

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple.

**Defining :**

```
proc myproc {} {

}
```

**calling :**

```
myproc
```

Since you are New, I advise you to go through tutorial point. They have simple and consolidated content.

Answer (score 1):

Procedure is a set of statements which is being preapeated in a program.

Syntax

```
proc <Name> {INPUTS} {
BODY
}
```

Eg:

```
proc add {m n} {
    set s 0
    set s [expr $m + $n]
    return $s
}

#Main Program Starts Here

set x 2
set y 3
set Result [add $x $y]
puts "$Result"
```

In the above example....in procedure we have provide a name (`add`) to the set of statements which can be call in the main program.

Answer (score 1):

### Any amount of arguments

What maybe would come in handy is using `args`.
By using `args` you can pass any amount of arguments to your procedure.

```
proc withAnyNumberOfArguments {args} {
    if {$args eq ""} {
        puts "got no arguments"
    } 
    foreach arg $args {
        puts "got $arg"
    }
}
```

---

### Optional Arguments

Another tip: Enclosing arguments with `{` `}` makes them optional arguments.

```
proc atLeastOneArgument {a1 {args}} {
    puts -nonewline "got a1=$a1"
    foreach arg $args {
        puts -nonewline " and $arg"
    }
    puts "."
}
```

---

### Default Values

If you want to have default values you can specify them as follows:

```
proc putsTime { {secondsSinceBeginOfEpoch "now"} } {
    if {$secondsSinceBeginOfEpoch eq "now"} {
        set secondsSinceBeginOfEpoch [clock seconds]
    }
    return [clock format $secondsSinceBeginOfEpoch]
}
```

### Some Example Calls

```
1 % withAnyNumberOfArguments
got no arguments

2 % withAnyNumberOfArguments one
got one

3 % withAnyNumberOfArguments ready steady go!
got ready
got steady
got go!


4 % atLeastOneArgument "this is one argument" ;# because its in double quotes
got a1=this is one argument.

5 % atLeastOneArgument 3 2 1 go!
got a1=3 and 2 and 1 and go!.


6 % puts [formatTime]
Fri Dec 18 16:39:43 CET 2015

7 % puts [formatTime 0]
Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, I would recommend using tcltutor.exe (available from http://tcltutor.software.informer.com/3.0b/) to learn TCL.

It'll have a chapter on Subroutines that'll help you define a TCL proc without and with arguments.

Regards
Sharad

Answer (score 1):

To create a TCL procedure without any parameter you should use the proc keyword followed by the procedure name then the scope of your procedure.

```
proc hello_world {} {
   // Use puts to print your output in the terminal.
   // If your procedure return data use return keyword.
}
```

You can use the created procedure by simply calling its name:
   hello_world

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on previous questions about writing procs. I personally feel this is one of the better ways to write a procedure in tcl.

**Code**

```
proc sampleProc args {

   # Defaults
   array set options {-device router0 -ip "10.16.1.62"}

   # Read args
   array set options $args

   # Assign
   set device $options(-device)
   set ip $options(-ip)

   # Usage
   puts "Device under use is $device and IP is  $ip"

   # Return 
   return "${sd} :: $ip"
}
```

**Execution**

```
tclsh> source sampleProc.tcl
Device under use is router0 and IP is 10.16.1.62
router0 :: 10.16.1.62
```